# SE network ads broken on HTTPS

Tags: bug, advertising, ssl

I happened to notice that, while browsing SE over HTTPS, a blank ad-shaped spot sometimes appeared in the sidebar.  Looking more closely, I found the following piece of HTML in it:

```html
<script src="http://stackexchange.com/ads/launched-question/js?id=SE20-ad-container"
type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Notice the `http:` script URL, which naturally gets blocked as insecure when viewing the page over HTTPS.

Sure enough, loading the script with the protocol changed to `https:` brought up a nice ad for [a scifi.SE question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54419/why-doesnt-starfleet-have-personal-shields) in place of the empty box:

[image: Screenshot]

I like these pretty ads, and I wish I could see more of them, even over HTTPS.  Removing the `http:` prefix from the script URL to make it protocol-relative ought to fix it.

(Ps. Sorry, I forgot to take screenshot of the empty space.  It looked the same as above, except with blank space where the ad is.)

---

**Edit:** OK, I spotted it again, and this time I managed to grab a screenshot of the broken ad space in the wild, along with its HTML code as seen in the dev tools:

[image: Screenshot #2]

Comment: Pps. If there's a specific term for these within-network ads, please tell me.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for bringing this to our attention. It's been passed along to employees of greater intelligence and wisdom than myself.

Any relevant updates will come here.